# cmake target_sources() - all targets

Tags: cmake

In my project, I have a top-level CMakeLists.txt with several `add_executable()` calls, defining several targets, `T1`, `T2`, ..., `Tn`. I have `m` subdirectories, each with their own `CMakeLists.txt`, each consisting of `n` lines, like so:

```
target_sources(T1 ...)
target_sources(T2 ...)
...
target_sources(Tn ...)
```

These lines are identical except for the target name.

Whenever I want to add a new executable, I have to add a new `target_sources()` line to `m` separate CMakeLists.txt files. Also, whenever a new source file gets added to one of those `m` subdirectories, I have to add an entry to each of the `n` lines in that CMakeLists.txt file. This is quite laborious.

**Is there a better way to do this**? I tried to look through the `target_sources` documentation, but couldn't find an obvious solution.

Comment: There is no special function in CMake to add a source file to all executables. You could write a function or macro, which just does all the needed actions. So single-line call to that function will trigger all these actions.

Comment: Could you just add all of your source files to a library and link that library in every executable? I would think that's the intended way to solve this. Depending on your use-case you could also have one library per subdirectory.

Comment: Within the subdirectories you could clearly use a `foreach` loop to shorten the code. This could be based on a list variable set before `ad_subdirectory` in the main `CMakeLists.txt`: `foreach(TGT IN LISTS TARGETS_TO_ADD_TO) target_sources(${TGT} ...) endforeach()`. You should probably create a static, interface or object library to collect the sources instead though...

Comment: Adding to a library is indeed the way to go. The thought escaped me because of how the file/directory structure evolved. Thanks!